# proper way of NATing and Routing when using TUN interface with iptables

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, ip-forwarding, tun

edit: I'm a newbie in networking and discovering new things :)

I created a TUN interface programmatically and able to interact with.

I set it up and running by
`ifconfig myTun 10.10.1.1/24 up`

and its up and running as I can see it in `ifconfig` and pinging `10.10.1.1`

and to make 100% sure if my TUN interface is up and running with my written problem I did following:

I pinged `10.10.1.2` and the packet is received in my program, I wrote it back to tun then received it again in a loop.

now I am sure all packets **FROM** or **TO** `10.10.1.x` are being received by and written to TUN without any problem.

when I write a packet with **any destination IP outside** the `10.10.1.x` it successfully written to TUN but no answered received to TUN.

after searching and reading lots of article I figured its silently being dropped by the kernel.

I read lots of Q/A about TUN interfaces in serverfault.com and I found out that I've missed a serious part in my Logic which is **ROUTING**.

my final understanding is:
the packet is OK and received by the network stack in linux, but the kernel doesn't know what to do with the packet because of its weird destination. then I discovered I must specify some routing for the kernel in **iptables** and enabling `net.ipv4.ip_forward` but doesn't know how to.

***my final goal is:***

*when I send any packet with any destination outside `10.10.1.x` to the TUN, it must be routed to my main interface (which has access to internet, and is `wlps020f3`) and any result of that packet receive back to my TUN interface*

how to configure **NAT** in **iptables** to workaround?

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable IPv4 forwarding](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux):

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

[NAT traffic](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-network-administrators/1565924002/ch11s03.html) from the tunnel interface behind your wireless address:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlps020f3 -j MASQUERADE
```

Neither of these changes will survive a reboot. The top link and [this one](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-save-iptables-firewall-rules-permanently-on-linux/) have more info on that aspect.

Comment: that worked once. after relaunching the program it didn't work. and I checked both ip forwarding and nat rules in iptabbles they exist. and do that forward any destination except the interface subnet which is 10.10.1.x??? because I need the clients on that subnet interact with each other too.

Comment: @user3840019 I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working after relaunching. Yes it should be forwarding to any destination outside 10.10.1.0/24 which is the ip/mask on your  interface. There are probably some technicalities since I believe a tun interface is supposed to be a point to point link so there really shouldnt be more than 2 devices on the link, but I haven't played with it enough to give strong feedback. Try running a tcpdump and looking at the traffic through the machine.

Comment: I've facd two problems here: 1. after setting up the interface I must ping a subnet to make it running otherwise its not running. 2. there is a routing dead loop there I think, because the tun sends me repeatitive packets

Comment: thanks @user989088 ! the problem was in my code which ignored packets in my weak epoll implementation

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was having trouble getting my home-baked VPN to run and you prompted me to look at the firewall.